# Adding constraints to an abstract type

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, object-oriented-database

I have this type that I have created :

`create type baseType as Object(...) NOT Instantiable not Final`

and I'd like to add constraints to some fields. The problem is that this type in `not instantiable` and therefore, I can't add a constraint to its fields. So then, when I create my inheriting types

```
create type childType1 under baseType (...) 

create type childType2 under baseType  (...)
```

I'll have to add constraints to all the children tables. Is this the correct way to go? I thought there would be a way to add the constraints on the common fields only in the parent type. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add constraints to object types at all - constraints are on a table. If the object is not instantiable, you can't have a table based on it, ergo no constraints on it.

I guess the answer would be to make the object type Instantiable. Then you can create a table based on it with constraints. Of course, these constraints won't be "inherited" by the child types.

All that said, however, I personally avoid Oracle object types when I can.